# Python flash game hack (memory reading)

Tags: python, flash, memory

I'm trying to write an application in Python to read a string from the memory of another flash application that is running in my browser. What functions should I use? Do you know any good tutorials?

Comment: you should research IPCs (Inter Process Communication)

Comment: Accessing other processes' memory is never a straightforward task, and is always platform dependent, but if you're on windows you may want to check [pymem](https://github.com/srounet/Pymem)

Comment: @cmd the question title leads me to believe he isn't the author of the flash application...

Comment: @goncalopp looking back you are probably right.